# @WithMockUser: Use a custom GrantedAuthority class instead of SimpleGrantedAuthority

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, mocking

I'm building a permission based access control with hierarchically permissions for a spring project. For this, I'm extending the `GrantedAuthority` object to a `Permission`. A custom `PermissionVoter` will finally draw benefits out of this, as the single permission parts can be retrieved.
This works as expected. The only problem are my integration tests.

With the annotation `@WithMockUser` I can mock a security context. By default this mocking method will create `SimpleGrantedAuthority`s. Expecting `Permission`s in my voter, this obviously is not going to work. Can I configure `@WithMockUser` to use my custom `GrantedAuthority` class?

PS. I'm intentionally not using Shiro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could instead use `@WithUserDetails`which takes a userDetailsService as parameter e.g. `userDetailsServiceBeanName = "mockedUserDetailsService"`and a User ("value")

You can then mock your Users and their GrantedAuthorities with the mocked UserDetailsService.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is the only way.